# How to copy some of the dependencies jars in Gradle

Tags: gradle

Let's say I have this dependency in Gradle:

```
   providedCompile(
        'javax:javaee-api:7.0',
        'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.4',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.5.4',
        'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.10.3',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.5.4',
 )
```

(I use providedCompile from war plugin as ai)

I have that for compile time but after everything is built, I need to copy the jars used in some (not all) of those dependencies to a couple of directories to configure them as Libraries in my Liberty Server, after that I create a Docker with that. For example I need to exclude ehcache jars as they are parte of the persistence engine in the app server.

I have tried:

```
task copyRuntimeLibs(type: Copy) {
    from (configurations. providedCompile - 'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.10.3')
    into "build/docker/dependenciesLibrary"
}
```

but it won't work. Jars from ehcache are still copied.

How can I create a copy task in Gradle that gets jars from, for example, those jackson dependencies (but not copying javaee-api ones)

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
task copyRuntimeLibs(type: Copy) {
    from (configurations.providedCompile){
        exclude 'ehcache-2.10.3.jar'
    }
    into "build/docker/dependenciesLibrary"
 }
```

and also

```
task copyRuntimeLibs(type: Copy) {
    from (configurations.providedCompile){
        exclude 'ehcache*.jar'
    }
    into "build/docker/dependenciesLibrary"
}
```

and both will work fine,

But actually i don't know if there are a way to use **'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.10.3'** direct instead of using **'ehcache-2.10.3.jar'** or **exclude 'ehcache*.jar'**